# Телеграмм бот не отправляет ответ на мое сообщение

Tags: c++, telegram-bot, libcurl

В общем должны работать так: я пишу боту randnum, и он мне посылает рандомное число. Раз я тут, то соответственно ничего не работает. Сообщение он не отправляет. И в чем проблема понять не могу. То ли он сообщение не распознал, то ли отправлять не захотел. Написано конечно же на с++ и использованием libcurl.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string urlEncode(const std::string &value)
{
    std::ostringstream escaped;
    escaped.fill('0');
    escaped << std::hex;

    for (char c : value)
    {
        if (isalnum(c) || c == '-' || c == '_' || c == '.' || c == '~')
        {
            escaped << c;
        }
        else
        {
            escaped << '%' << std::setw(2) << int((unsigned char)c);
        }
    }

    return escaped.str();
}

void sendMessage(const std::string& botToken, const std::string& chatId, const std::string& message) {
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        std::string encmsg = urlEncode(message);
        std::string url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botToken + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + chatId + "&text=" + encmsg;

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if (res != CURLE_OK) {
            std::cerr << "Ошибка при отправке сообщения: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}

void chrnum(const std::string& botToken, const std::string& chatId, const std::string& m) {
    if (m == "randnum") {
        std::random_device rd;
        std::mt19937 gen(rd());
        std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(1, 100);

        int randomNum = dis(gen);

        // Отправить сообщение с случайным числом
        sendMessage(botToken, chatId, "Случайное число: " + std::to_string(randomNum));
    }
}

int main() {
    CURL* curlptr = curl_easy_init();
    if (curlptr) {
        std::string botToken = "";
        std::string chatId = "";

        std::string url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + botToken + "/getUpdates?chat_id=" + chatId;

        while (true) {
            curl_easy_setopt(curlptr, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());

            std::string response;

            curl_easy_setopt(curlptr, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &response);

            CURLcode code = curl_easy_perform(curlptr);
            if (code == CURLE_OK) {
                // Проверить и обработать полученные сообщения
                chrnum(botToken, chatId, response);
            } else {
                std::cout << "Ошибка при выполнении запроса: " << curl_easy_strerror(code) << std::endl;
            }

            // Задержка перед следующим запросом
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }

        curl_easy_cleanup(curlptr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Само собой токен и чат id были заменены на верные. Интернет стабилен.
Код говно и я это прекрасно понимаю, так что можете даже не пытаться сказать, я знаю. Все равно потом поделю по хедерам.

Comment: Что? Кто-то пишет телеграмм-ботов на C++?))